# problem with proccessing info from https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I used https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/openid_connect/getting_started.html documentation to let my users to login with their yahoo accounts , all steps is working even I could return Example Response in  yahoo document. The problem is I can't retrieve user data automatically because it will redirect out of my website, when I retrieve the "id_token" which is including user's profile details , the URL is : https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token and page has redirected . please help me, what should I do to handle this problem.

```
 <form id="yahoo-auth-frm" action="https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <input type="text" id="yahoo-auth-frm-client_id" name="client_id" value="{{env('YAHOO_CLIENT_ID')}}">
        <input type="text" id="yahoo-auth-frm-client_secret" name="client_secret" value="{{env('YAHOO_CLIENT_SECRET')}}">
        <input type="text" id="yahoo-auth-frm-redirect_uri" name="redirect_uri" value="{{env('YAHOO_REDIRECT_LINK')}}">
        <input type="text" id="yahoo-auth-frm-code" name="code" value="{{ (isset($_GET['code']) && !empty($_GET['code'])) ? $_GET['code'] : '' }}">
        <input type="text" id="yahoo-auth-frm-grant_type" name="grant_type" value="authorization_code">
        <input class="" type="submit" value="send">
    </form>
```

[See This photo - this is my result after sending post request with all parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAnnZ.png)

needless to say that : id_token has 3 part and the second one is payload , if you use base64_decode($payload) , you can retrieve user profile info

Comment: if you have a problem with some code, you'll need to show it. We can't fix what we can't see.

Comment: I don't have any problem in my codes , according to yahoo documentation after sending a POST request to this URL : https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth with required parameters , yahoo will return these fields : access_token , refresh_token , expires_in , token_type , id_token    and with decoding id_token I can retrieve User profile data , the problem is when I send this request with post method , I will redirect to another URL , I want to avoid it and retrieve the fields in my webpage. that all it , am I clear ?

Comment: "when I send this request with post method , I will redirect to another URL "....ok but without seeing your code it's still unclear how/why that might be happening. Are you posting this data direct from a HTML form? Or are you using PHP code to interact with the Yahoo API? Or using AJAX maybe? We simply do not know exactly what you are doing. Therefore we cannot tell you how to resolve it properly.

Comment: it is so simple bro : login with Yahoo API to my web page, I did this before with Google API for login in my website , but It was very different

Comment: This is my error if I try with AJAX to send my form :Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token' from origin 'https://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: ok well either Yahoo API doesn't allow CORS, or you have to do something to register your site (Google have a similar procedure which you may have followed for their API).

Comment: do you have a solution with yahoo ?

Comment: Not personally, i haven't used it. I saw your question because it was tagged PHP, and I commented originally because I wanted to suggest you added some relevant code so that either myself or others might be able to help you. I thought perhaps there was some specific issue in the PHP which might be obvious to me or others directly. But also someone with direct experience with the Yahoo API would still  have a better chance of understanding your problem if they can actually see the way you are trying to use the API.

Comment: So now I can see you have shown some HTML which shows a form which posts directly back to Yahoo. And I can see it returns a JSON object. But you can't use that object because you've posted directly to the URL and got the response in the browser display, rather than being returned via code. You clearly need to use either PHP or Javascript to handle the request rather than using a HTML form. That way the JSON response will come back to your code rather than showing on-screen. Unfortunately from a quick search online I can't see any kind of ready-made JS or PHP client, unlike what Google provides

Comment: What part of it don't you understand how to do? Have you previously tried to make a HTTP request using Javascript and/or PHP? In JS you use AJAX, in PHP you would use cURL usually , as the client. It looks like you already tried AJAX, but ran into the CORS issue, which is not something you can solve via a code sample - it's a configuration issue on the server side. Look at your yahoo app settings (like you went through in the getting started guide) and see if it has anything to help you with CORS. If not, you'll have to communicate with the API via PHP.

Comment: you right, would you please give me a sample , I didn't have experience in this case for communicate with API via PHP or HTTP requesting with javascript

Comment: Well firstly please learn how to use cURL (by finding examples and documentation online. Then try for yourself to create the request, and see what happens. Ask us if you get stuck. Otherwise even if I give you a sample, you would not understand it properly, or be able to re-use it or modify it. Best way to learn new things is to try it. And besides this site is not a free write-my-code service, or a tutorial site. Now you understand the basic idea of what you have to to. Next step is to try it. Then if you get stuck, ask us a specific question about it.